# LibGDX / Java or XNA / C#

Tags: c#, java, xna, libgdx

I am curious to know what will be better for game programming - LibGDX / Java or XNA / C#.
I have advanced knowledge in both C# and Java, and I really want to get into game development, and develop indie games and such.

So what are the pros and cons of XNA and LibGDX, what do you prefer personally and why?

Java - LibGDX is cross platform and uses OpenGL.

C# - XNA is for windows only (you can use monogame but it will hurt performance and other things). Unfortunately, XNA is not going to be supported anymore but I still see people that recommend it over LibGDX. (XNA is more popular and has more tutorials then libGDX).

So please help me decide which one I should use, I really don't know which to choose.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used C# or XNA, but I can definitely recommend LibGDX. It is not just cross platform, but also pretty easy to use and in my opinion pretty well documented. It has a healthy, active community and you can even find all main developers in their IRC channel #libgdx.

It has everything built-in and supports every common platform. From Graphics (2D+3D) to Sound over Input to Physics (2D+3D), Networking and utilities like JSON, UI and different TiledMap loaders+renderers. Everything is included.

According to Google Trends libgdx is pretty much "on the rise".

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Now I have a way to start, I see people don't understand the question correctly, I have a trouble to pick because XNA is not supported anymore, and its not a cross platform but many people still recommend me to use XNA, and I don't understand what is so good about XNA that people still recommend it over libGDX ( XNA is shit, i mean - not cross platform, not supported and such..